# Dead code java eclipse

Tags: java, dead-code

I am trying to check if the word given by the user already exists in the text file or a substring of it already exists. Here's my code:

```
String ans = null;
Scanner scanner = null;
do
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a new word: ");
    String Nword = scan.next();
    System.out.print("And its appropriate Hint: ");
    String Nhint = scan.next();

    Word word = new Word(Nword , Nhint);
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Charbel\\Desktop\\Dictionary.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    scanner = new Scanner(file);
    if (scanner != null)
    {
        String line;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            line = scanner.next();
            for(int i = 0 ; i<line.length(); i++)
                if ((line.equals(Nword)) || (Nword.equals(line.substring(i))))
                {
                    System.out.println("The word already exists.");
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file , true);
        writer.write(word.toString());
        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("Your word has successfuly added.");
        System.out.print("\nWould you like to add another word ?\nPress 0 to continue.");
        ans = scan.next();
    }
} while(ans.equals("0"));
```

Eclipse said that the statements after the `else` condition are "Dead Code" and I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe your `scanner` can never be `null`? Take a look at the documentation for `Scanner`. It will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the `file` is not present, but it will never be `null`. Hence your `else`-statement is never executed and so it is `dead code`. :-)

Comment: In Java dead code is code that will never be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

`scanner` is initialized, can never be `null`, so the `else` statement will never be reached.

See the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29):

> Throws:    
>      [`FileNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) - if source is not found

So if the `file` doesn't exists, `scanner` won't be `null`, you'll have an *exception*.

Comment: then how can i say that if the word doesnt exist or its substring then write it

Answer (score 2):

```
scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

This statement is creating a new instance here. So this:
    `if (scanner != null)` will never be false.

Comment: then how can i say that if the word doesnt exist or its substring then write it

Answer (score 0):

`Dead-Code` is which never gets executed, for example:

```
if(true) {
// do something
}else {
// do something else <-- this is dead code, or else-block is dead code
}
```

In your case since `Scanner` is getting created before `if(scanner != null)` there is no way of execution of associated `else`. If `Scanner` creation fails error will be thrown again in which `else` will not be executed, hence from compiler point-of-view no chance of `else` block getting executed hence `dead-code`.

`if-else` would have made sense if `scanner` instance is passed as argument.

To solve this, `else` should be removed!

Following should correct your code:

```
                scanner = new Scanner(file);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
                if (scanner != null) {
                    String line;
                    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                        line = scanner.next();
                        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                            if ((line.equals(""))
                                    || ("".equals(line.substring(i)))) {
                                System.out.println("The word already exists.");
                                break;
                            } else {
                                writer.write(word.toString());
                                writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
                                writer.flush();
                                System.out.println("Your word has successfuly added.");
                                System.out.print("\nWould you like to add another word ?\nPress 0 to continue.");
                                ans = scan.next();
                            }
                    }
                }
                writer.close();
```

Comment: then how can i say that if the word doesn't exist or its substring then write it

Comment: You want to write only when `equals` or `substring` match fails, right?